# Bayesian inference and a logistic weight control problem

Tags: bayesian, modeling, application

Currently I have a lot of problems to select which I want to work on. For some I already got ideas on how to solve it. However, I haven't dived deep into Bayesian inference so far but, from what I have read, it looks like the following problem should be perfectly fit to Bayesian inference/Bayesian networks. Essentially, I just want to check if the approach does make sense, and if its spending now time to dive deeper in to bayesian inference.

Assume we have $n$ different products $q_j$ with "initial" weights $w_j$.
These initial weights are error-prone, due to human weighing, transmission errors and economic cost and I want to find the "true" weights $\theta_j$.
Of course it might be that $\theta_j=w_j$ but for some $j$ there might be a (huge) difference in these two quantities.

Now on a given day, we dispatch $m$ orders, and each order consists of $l_k$ ($k\in 1,\ldots, m$) products  $q_j$. Each of the $m$ orders contains a basket $B_m$ of (randomly) chosen products. Typically the size of $B_m$ is larger than $1$ and most products $q_j$ will be in a basket with at least one other product. With a precise scale (e.g. error less than 0.5 gram), we weigh each of the $m$ baskets.

If the sum of the weights inside a basket deviates more than 2 grams from the corresponding "initial" sum of weights (the sum of the corresponding $w_j$), the order is considered to be false and is rechecked (and will be investigated by an employer, (the checking process)), otherwise it is assumed to be correct.

So the question is, can one increase the precision of the estimate of $\theta_j$ in this process?

To me it seems that bayesian inference/networks are the right tools here.
So introducing the vectors $\theta=(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n)$ and $B=(b_1,\ldots,B_m)$, we should find $$P(\theta| B) =\frac{P(B)P(B|\theta)}{P(\theta)}$$
Is this correct or are there different suggestions?

Problems for me:

How to choose the right prior distribution $P(\theta)$ (and also $P(B)$)? The "initial" weights $w_j$ should enter (maybe as means of a Gaussian, if so , how to choose the variance), but which distribution makes the most sense?

How does one get the right $\theta_j$ in the posterior? Just get the mean/mode of the resulting distribution?

Can (and if how) those estimates be increased after performing the"checking" process?

So far no information of the checking process enters: Possible things that can happen:
I.e. the basket weight is interpreted as falsely though the content is correct (obviously at least one initial weight is false, this information should definetly be used but might be costly to obtain).

Additionally, we could gather the information which products where wrongly put in the basket and which product where picked to correct the basket (this is of course costly)

Any help, hint or reference for a starting point is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify what $\theta_j$ is?

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry for the inconvenience. The $\theta_j$ are the "true" weights of the products $q_j$